# Twice page refresh is needed to get the input data from MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

When i enter new values to form input field and submit them, then twice page reload needed to get the new values.

like you can see the `$balance_2` in the 7th line. This line sum all row values of every row and and record the value in `Balance` column of every row and after pressing submit button then it goes to update_2.php file to update the database and when in click on

```
<a style='left: -18%; top: 100%; position: absolute; color: white; font-family: Roboto, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;  width: 170px; font-weight: 600;' href='index_2.php'>Click here to go back</a>
```

button in update_2.php file and go back to the main page then the form values are not updated till i reload it again.

I want that when i click on `Click here to go back` button then new values should be shown and there must not be need to reload the page twice.

***This is my codes***

```
$id_2 = $row['ID'];
$Budget_2 = $row['Budget'];
$Availed_in_Regions_2 = $row['Availed_in_Regions'];
$Requested_in_KBL_2 = $row['Requested_in_KBL'];
$Received_in_KBL_2 = $row['Received_in_KBL'];
$Availed_in_KBL_2 = $row['Availed_in_KBL'];

$balance_2 = $Availed_in_Regions_2 + $Requested_in_KBL_2 + $Received_in_KBL_2 + $Availed_in_KBL_2;
$con2->query("UPDATE Office_Operations f1, (SELECT SUM(balance) AS bal FROM Office_Operations ) f2 SET ytotal6_2 = bal WHERE f1.id = 1;");
$con2->query("UPDATE Office_Operations SET Balance = $balance_2 WHERE id = $id_2");


echo "<div class='calc_container'"; if($row['ID']==1) echo " style='margin-bottom:40px;'"; echo "> 

    <input type='hidden' class='id_3' name='id[]' value='".$row['ID']."'>

    <input type='text' class='budget_3' name='Budget[]' value='".$row['Budget']."'>

    <input type='text' class='avail_region_3' name='Availed_in_Regions[]' value='".$row['Availed_in_Regions']."'>

    <input type='text' class='req_kbl_3' name='Requested_in_KBL[]' value='".$row['Requested_in_KBL']."'>

    <input type='text' class='rec_kbl_3' name='Received_in_KBL[]' value='".$row['Received_in_KBL']."'>

    <input type='text' class='avail_kbl_3' name='Availed_in_KBL[]' value='".$row['Availed_in_KBL']."'>

    <input type='text' class='balance_3' name='Balance[]' value='".$row['Balance']."'>

    </div>";}
```

Comment: What does your update_2.php file look like? And where does the anchor tag for 'Click to go back' live?

Comment: This is [update_2.php](http://jsfiddle.net/9tnjhdrx/) and Click to go back lives in update_2.php.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective:

1. Put all the `input` tags inside of `form` tag that uses `action=""` (to the same URL)

OR

2. Process the request with AJAX. When clicked on anchor `a` use `onclick` then define the listener function that makes the AJAX call and updates the `input` fieldS on successful response (parse the response accordingly). See [using JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Also, it would be better if you escape the query input values. For MySQL see some posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688/what-do-i-need-to-escape-when-sending-a-query), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-attacks) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: See the `input` code snippet here: http://codepad.org/gK6icyD3 . What I did was just wrapped the inputs inside of form that send the request to the current URL in _POST variable when the button (newly created) is pushed.

Comment: i replaced it but nothing have changed

Answer (score 0):

Your list page or your main page is the `index_2.php` and your `update_2.php` is where the `Click here to go back` button is located.

### Summary:

index_2.php

- List of data
- Also where the form is

update_2.php

- where the `Click here to go back` button is located

When the data is submitted from your `index_2.php`, it will go to `update_2.php`, but does nothing but offers only the back button.

The only time the `UPDATE query` will run is when the user clicks the `Click here to go back` button.

### SOLUTION:

- Put your `UPDATE query` in your `update_2.php`
- Use the `header()` function to redirect the user back to `index_2.php` after the query

#### Sample Code:

index_2.php:

```
<form action="update_2.php" method="POST">

  <!-- INSERT HERE YOUR INPUT FIELDS -->
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

update_2.php:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    /* INSERT HERE YOUR UPDATE QUERIES */
    header("LOCATION:index_2.php"); /* REDIRECT USER BACK TO index_2.php */

  } /* END OF ISSET SUBMIT */

?>
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding  
This is [update_2.php](http://jsfiddle.net/9tnjhdrx/) and Click to go back lives in update_2.php.